# How to fix a C1010 error without turning off precompiled headers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers

So,
I have to use precompiled headers in my VS 2005 project.  Now I have a shared source file that does not have a #include "stdafx.h"... How can I include the shared source file in my project without adding stdafx.h to the top of the source file and without turning off precompiled headers??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers -> Create/Use precompiled headers -> Not using ...

Comment: oh snap.  I figured it was something simple like that and I'm just being noob.  Thanks... I'm still getting familiar with VS :)

Comment: This turns off PCH, which is exactly what the OP wants to avoid... Use /FI, instead.

Comment: This option allows you to turns off pch for this file - which probably is exactly what the op wants. Where did you get your interpretation of the op wanting to use precompiled headers for the source file from?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the properties (context menu) for that file, in the C/C++ - Precompiled Header section.

Change "Create/Use Precompiled Header" to "Not Using Precompiled Headers".

Note - I just checked this in VC++2003 - the option *might* have moved in VC++2005 or 2008, but I doubt it. Even if it has moved, though, it shouldn't be hard to find.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if this was specific to MFC...  I've never used pre-compiled headers before.  Thanks!

Comment: This turns off PCH... Use /FI, instead.

Comment: @Xavier - It turns off PCH for *ONE* *SPECIFIC* cpp file. This is rarely a big deal, and can be beneficial. If every header for the project is included by a single stdafx.h header, which is included by every cpp file (as VC++ encourages), *any* change to *any* header causes *every* cpp file in the whole project to need rebuilding. Of course that suggests explicitly selecting different precompiled header files for different cpp files - but the options are pretty obvious, on the same page as the "Not Using..." option, so why state the obvious - esp as it's not always worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the ['Force Include'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84%28VS.80%29.aspx) option: "This option has the same effect as specifying the file with double quotation marks in an #include directive on the first line of every source file specified on the command line, in the CL environment variable, or in a command file."

Very handy to introduce PreCompiled Headers without changing all the source files...